# Working of integer testing (is.integer(2/2) returns FALSE)

Tags: r

Why does the following return `FALSE`:

```
is.integer(4/4)
is.integer(4/2)
is.integer(2/2)
```

Any idea?

I can do the following:

```
4 %% 4
4 %% 2
2 %% 2
```

But my goal here is to understand the function `is.integer`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From `?is.integer`

> is.integer(x) does **not** test if x contains integer numbers! For that,
>   use round, as in the function is.wholenumber(x) in the examples.

```
is.wholenumber <-function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
> is.wholenumber(4/4)
# [1] TRUE
```

R stores `4/4` as `double`:

```
> storage.mode(4/4)
# [1] "double"
```

You could do:

```
x <- 4/4
storage.mode(x) <- "integer"
> is.integer(x)
# [1] TRUE
```